# Adding OAuth to azure API management - Redirect URI is null

Tags: azure, api, oauth-2.0, azure-api-management

I am not sure if I am setting this up right or not. I am trying to follow this guide from MS :

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-howto-protect-backend-with-aad

We have an API that we want to expose to the outside world, so I have placed it behind the azure Api Management Service. That all works, and I can use the test window in the API management to call my API (with the token) and get results fine.
Now that we are going to expose to the outside world, I wanted to enable Oauth so that our clients need to authorize to use it.

I got all the way to setting up Oauth on the APIM instance, and in the RedirectUrl section I see this :

[image: RedirectURL]

So when I go to add the authentication to the client app registration, using that URL I get :

[image: Client app auth]

The only difference that I can see in the setup steps, is that I am trying to add our CMS application as the FE that is gonna be calling the API, and in this walkthrough they mention the developer console. But I figured it would be the same setup.

Any ideas, or is there a better guide for this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I test it in my side, it seems the redirect url will be `null/sign....` if the APIM is in consumption tier. The official [document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/api-management/api-management-features) also shows us we can't integrate the Developer Portal with Azure AD because there is no Developer Portal when you use consumption plan for your APIM.

[image]

Comment: ah ok. So i will need to upgrade to developer.

Comment: Hi @evolmonster If the answer helps your question, could you please [mark]((https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work/5235#5235)) it as "accepted", thanks inadvance.